# Selenium WebDriver C# and Omnibug

Tags: c#, selenium, firebug

I need to add extension for Firefox - it is addon for Firebug and calls Omnibug. I use Selenium WeDriver with C#. I add firebug.xpi and netExport.xpi and this extensions appears in Firefox. Also I add Omnibug.xpi but it doesn't appeare in FF. Any ideas?

Full listing:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();

        profile.Clean();

        profile.AddExtension(@"D:\SELENIUM\selenium-dotnet-2.39.0\net40\netExport-0.8.xpi");
        profile.AddExtension(@"D:\SELENIUM\selenium-dotnet-2.39.0\net40\firebug-1.12.0.xpi");
        profile.AddExtension(@"D:\SELENIUM\selenium-dotnet-2.39.0\net40\omnibug-0.5.500.xpi");

        string output_dir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

        output_dir = Path.Combine(output_dir, "Firebugnetexports");

        profile.SetPreference("extensions.firebug.currentVersion", "1.12");
        profile.SetPreference("extensions.firebug.allPagesActivation", "on");
        profile.SetPreference("extensions.firebug.defaultPanelName", "net");
        profile.SetPreference("extensions.firebug.net.enableSites", true);
        profile.SetPreference("extensions.firebug.netexport.alwaysEnableAutoExport", true);
        profile.SetPreference("extensions.firebug.netexport.showPreview", true); // preview
        profile.SetPreference("extensions.firebug.netexport.sendToConfirmation", false);
        profile.SetPreference("extensions.firebug.netexport.pageLoadedTimeout", 3000);
        profile.SetPreference("extensions.firebug.netexport.autoExportToFile", true);
        profile.SetPreference("extensions.firebug.netexport.Automation",true);
        profile.SetPreference("extensions.firebug.netexport.alwaysEnableAutoExport", true);
        profile.SetPreference("extensions.firebug.netexport.showPreview", false);
        profile.SetPreference("extensions.firebug.netexport.defaultLogDir", output_dir);

        profile.SetPreference("extensions.firebug.omnibug.enableSites", true);
        profile.SetPreference("extensions.omnibug.userPattern", "om.");
        profile.SetPreference("extensions.omnibug.enableFileLogging", true);
        profile.SetPreference("extensions.omnibug.logFileName", "omnibug_log");
        profile.SetPreference("extensions.omnibug.alwaysExpand", true);

        if (!Directory.Exists(output_dir))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(output_dir);
        }

        IWebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
        webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.ringcentral.com");
        Console.WriteLine(output_dir);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know it must be in lowercase s in profile.setPreference instead of  profile.SetPreference

such as

```
    profile.setPreference("extensions.firebug.omnibug.enableSites", true);
    profile.setPreference("extensions.omnibug.userPattern", "om.");
    profile.setPreference("extensions.omnibug.enableFileLogging", true);
    profile.setPreference("extensions.omnibug.logFileName", "omnibug_log");
    profile.setPreference("extensions.omnibug.alwaysExpand", true);
```